# intellitrace standalone recorder

Tags: intellitrace, historical-debugging

I know that Test Case Management app silently records intellitrace data dump files (http://blogs.msdn.com/jennifer/archive/2008/12/05/visual-studio-team-system-vsts-2010-making-testing-easier.aspx)

I was curious if there is a standalone version that allows to record intellitrace logs (e.g. something that would sit in the tray window).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VSTraceLog.exe under "Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\TraceDebugger Tools" could be what you are looking for.

VSTraceLog.exe /? to get the different options.

A simple example: `VSTracelog.exe launch /cp:CollectionPlan.xml /f:logfilename.tdlog TheExecutableToLog.exe`

You'll want to copy the file "Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\TraceDebugger Tools\en\CollectionPlan.xml" to a known location and modify it. Open the XML file and find "DiagnosticEventInstrumentation" set the enabled attribute to true. Optionally you can enable "TraceInstrumentation" as well. Enabling TraceInstrumentation would be like enabling Tools->Options->IntelliTrace->events and call information.

Comment: thanks a lot Evan, I am actually missing the executable that you mentioned in my install dir C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\TraceDebugger Tools. The only file that I have is a TraceLogProfiler.dll . Is this a separate install option when installing Visual Studio?

Comment: If you are on 64bit Windows look in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\TraceDebugger Tools.". 

Depending on the install options the quickest to find the location might be to create a basic console application. Set a breakpoint. F5 and hit the breakpoint. Fire up Process Explorer (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and then look at the properties for the IntelliTrace.exe to get the full path to its location.

Answer (score 3):

With Visual Studio 2012 there is a fully supported standalone version available.  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29036

Answer (score 2):

You might also be interested in http://naveensrinivasan.com/2010/04/28/useintellitracewithoutvsnet/, which describes how to run IntelliTrace on PCs that don't have Visual Studio installed. In this case it would apply to you if you aren't running VS2010 Ultimate.